# Green's Function Method for a Spring and mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, greens-functions

[image: Past exam paper question]

I think I've done part a) correctly and I have a general solution. However, I now have two unknown constants in my general solution and, as far as I can see, only one condition ($x(0)=-1$) with which to find these constants and provide the specific form required. Can anyone explain to me where a second condition is implied/found or have I done something wrong in answering part a)?

My answer for part a) was:
\begin{align}
x(t)
&= 9(\exp(-t/3) - \exp(-2t/3)) \\
&- (3/2)(\exp(t) + \exp(-t) + A(\exp(-2t/3)) \\
&+ B\exp(-t)
\end{align}

where $A$ and $B$ are constants, applying the initial condition $x(0)= -1$ I got $A+B=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you don't quite have part a correct, but this just might be a typo. My particular solution from the usual retarded Green's function is
\begin{equation}
x_p(t) = 9e^{-2t/3}-(9+3t)e^{-t}
\end{equation}
and adding the homogeneous solution
\begin{equation}
x_0(t) = Ae^{-2t/3}-Be^{-t}
\end{equation}
as you have, gives part a.

In part b the boundary conditions are $x(0)=-1$ and the particle is at rest, so
$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$ is zero at $t=0$, and you have the two conditions needed to solve for $A$ and $B$.